# How to center a fixed vertical nav css?

Tags: html, css

Soooo I want to know how to keep the nav fixed but also centered vertically.
Also if there's any suggestions to improve the code let me know plz:)

```
<nav>


<span style="color:#B80003; font-size:24px; text-decoration:underline;">Home</span>
<br>
 <a href="music.html">Music</a>
<br>
<a href="pics.html">Pics</a>
<br>
<a href="tour.html">Tour</a>

</nav>


nav {
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-size:18px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: vertically aligned left

Comment: Then how is that centered?

Comment: i mean center from ugh idk how to say

Comment: center it vertically

Comment: center it vertically to the page??

Comment: yea but keep it fixed left too

Answer (score 0):

use this `top: 0;left: 0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;`

```css
nav {
  font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-size:18px;
  height:20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" style="color:#B80003; font-size:24px;">Home</a>
  <a href="music.html">Music</a>
  <a href="pics.html">Pics</a>
  <a href="tour.html">Tour</a>
</nav>
```

Edit 2
Ok this always used to work I didn't see you were using `<a>` elements just that the wrapper needs to take the height; all set check the snippet

Comment: it should be centered already to page, Do you want a different center?

Comment: it's just at the top of the page i want it to be centered

Comment: ok my bad check now I hope this answers the question. Added snippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-size:18px;
position: fixed;
/* top: 0; */
   left: 0;
 z-index: 9999;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<nav>


<span style="color:#B80003; font-size:24px; text-decoration:underline;">Home</span>
<br>
 <a href="music.html">Music</a>
<br>
<a href="pics.html">Pics</a>
<br>
<a href="tour.html">Tour</a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It;s not really clear what you are trying to do but I think this is it.

```css
nav {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" style="color:#B80003; font-size:24px;">Home</a>
  <a href="music.html">Music</a>
  <a href="pics.html">Pics</a>
  <a href="tour.html">Tour</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: yea i want it like that but make it fixed to the left